# How to change value in childnode

Tags: javascript, jquery

Today I have a problem. I can't get and change value in array **Childnotes**. I try find in stackoverflow but not results as expected

> var $this = $(this);

When Debug, I receive image follow:

[image]

I want to get value and change value in childNotes: NodeList[3] --> **1:img** --> change **attributes**: **src** in **img**

Comment: `$(this).children()` ..? Are you looking for this..?

Comment: PLease post your full code

Comment: what you exactly want?

Comment: I had to try >var imgS2 = $this.children().eq(1).attr("img");  But not value.. Can I help You???

Comment: show your html it is easy to clear your doubt?

Comment: I want to get and change value element "img" in array NodeList[3].

Answer (score 1):

I think that you would like to change some attr src from image tag inside your tag

So, you can use your reference $this (tag ) to find your specific image tag and do whatever your want:

```
...

var $this = $(this);
$this.find("img").attr("src", "some_value");

...
```

If you have more than one image tags and you want to change just the third tag, you should mark it with some "data-attribute", like this:

```
$this.find("img[data-changeable]").attr("src", "some_value");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like:

```
$(this).children("img").attr("src", "mycool_image.jpg");
```

This will find the direct children -> if you have them nested deeper, you can use `find()` instead.

```
$(this).find("img").attr("src", "mycool_image.jpg");
```

**EDIT**

If you want the n-th child `img` element then you can do:

```
$(this).find("img").eq(2).attr("src", "mycool_image.jpg");
```

**EDIT2**

To get the source before changing it simply do (by supplying the correspondent index to `eq()` of course):

```
var source = $(this).find("img").eq(2).attr("src");
```

Comment: Oh My God....I had done. But I want to get element src in img before change it. Can I Help you.. :)

Comment: Follow code is correct: var source = $(this).find("img").eq(0).attr("src");   ...... Thank you very much.